# BusinessObject .rep File

Tags: visual-studio, reportviewer, business-objects

I have a .rep File, I think it ist a file created with Visual Studio and Business Report.

There are no SQL Queries in the File. I looked with notepad. But how can I open it? I download the Report Viewer from Microsoft, but there is no exe-File to start it.

Have someone of you an Idea?

Without to install Visual Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Identifying the file

`.rep` is a common extension for a BusinessObjects Full Client document (later renamed to *Desktop Intelligence*).

According to the [FILEext](http://filext.com/file-extension/REP) site, such a document can be identified by looking at it with a HEX editor. The first 9 bytes should be `D0 CF 11 E0 A1 B1 1A E1 00`.

Having checked a `.rep` file I still had, the HEX signature didn't match. This may be due to the XI releases of Desktop Intelligence using the same extension but a different implementation. The newer format seems to be a ZIP file. Try renaming the file from `.rep` to `.zip` and see if you can open the file then (or open the `.rep` file in a text viewer; the first 2 characters should be `PK`).

Here's a screenshot of my `.rep` file opened as a ZIP archive:

[image: archive contents]

The rest of this post will assume it actually *is* a BusinessObject document.

### Opening the file

This is where things get tricky. Usually, such documents belong to a repository, which defines authorisations, thus preventing individual documents being sent around and opened by someone who doesn't have the necessary rights to do so.

If the document wasn't saved with all security settings removed (known as *Save for all users*), I'm afraid you won't be able to open it.

If it was (thus the file has no security defined on it), you'll still need a corresponding version of BusinessObjects Full Client / Desktop Intelligence to open the file. This application is part of the SAP BusinessObjects BI suite. The latest version that contains DeskI (as it's end-of-life currently) is SAP BusinessObjects XI 3.1. I doubt you'll be able to download a trial of this version, as it's already quite old.

### Getting the SQL queries

BusinessObjects documents are usually (not always) based on a *Universe*: a semantic abstraction layer that generates SQL queries depending on the objects selected by the report author. In short: you won't be able to retrieve the SQL statement without the underlying universe.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The first 9 Bytes in the file are: ec51 b81e 85eb 51a8